# Unable to access a docker image running in Azure Web App for Containers

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

I've created a docker image and added it to the Azure Container Registry. I've then deployed it to a Web App but am having trouble accessing the site. When I browse to it loads for a long time (minutes) and then get a 503 error 'service unavailable.

I thought it might be a port issue as my docker file has:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 15973
EXPOSE 44369
```

And have added the following key/value pair to the app settings: `WEBSITES_PORT`: `15973` but still doesn't return anything.

I thought that I'd go back to basics and use the quickstart from the web app for containers (`appsvc/sample-hello-world:latest`) but that does the same, can't actually start the app.

What could be the issue? Should it be as simple as point it to an image to get a website up and running? Is there another public template I can use as a basic image to see a container runnning?

---

Update

So I've tried running the image locally a suggested by @Charles. When it starts it definitely runs as if I don't pass environment variables (such as connection string) then I get the related error message.

The issue running locally is that after it's started I'm not sure how it's exposed. I've tried http://localhost:15973, http://localhost:44369, http://localhost/ and tried passing `-p 8080:80` and then http://localhost:8080 but they don't don't respond.

The response of starting the image is:

> Hosting environment: Production
>
> Content root path: /app
>
> Now listening on: http://[::]:80

I think that this is the problem with it being hosted in Azure as well, the requests aren't being routed through to the image.

What do I need to do to call the api in the image?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it for other people who look for it.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I try a test about Azure Web App for Containers and follow the steps in [Deploy a Docker/Go web app in Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker-go). It works well.

So, I suggest you can test your image on your local machine first. If it can work as you want on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've updated my question based on what you said. Going a bit off topic from my original question, but would be grateful for your help!

Comment: @ADringer The port which you should expose is that you used in the application. For example, if you use the port 1234 for your application, then you can expose like `targetPort:1234`. The targetPort is the port of the host node and port 1234 is the port you used in the container for your application.

Comment: so when doing `docker run` I would set `-p 15973:80`? How does this work with Azure Apps? I set `WEBSITES_PORT: 15973` but that didn't do it. Note that port 15973 is marked as exposed in my dockerfile

Comment: @ADringer Actually, you should make sure if the port 15973 is used by your application. For example, if you use the port 15973 for your application and you want to access your application from the Internet via port 80, you can set  with command `docker run -p 80:15973 image`.

Comment: @ADringer You learn something about Bind container ports to the host from [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/).

Comment: I've got a bit further with it now thanks to your comment. If I run `docker run -p 15973:80` locally then I can access it locally at http://127.0.0.1:15973. How do I go about exposing this in Azure though? Looking at the logs it appears to do a random port when running the image: `docker run -d -p 27253:15973`. Shouldn't the first port be 80/443?

Comment: If you execute the command `docker run -p 15973:80` and then you can access it as you say. It means you should expose the port in the Dockerfile and create the image. Then you can try the web app for container with the image again.